# Val-property cannot override var-property

Tags: kotlin, overriding

I thought `var` could be overridden as `val` with the only getter because it has both getter and setter. But this is impossible.

[image]

And, if override `val` that only has getter with `var` that has setter, no error occurs. I don't know how this is possible.

[image]

Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example (overriding `val` with `var`) is similar to this pseudocode:

```
open class Test {
    fun getA()
}

class Main : Test() {
    fun setA()
}
```

`Main` subclass just adds a new method, there is no reason why it would be not possible. Your first example (overriding `var` with `val`) would be similar to:

```
open class Test {
    fun getA()
    fun setA()
}

class Main : Test() {
    // remove setA() function
}
```

As you probably know, it is not possible to remove methods in subclasses, so it is not possible to override `var` with `val`.

Answer (score 1):

First the reason you can override val with a var is that it is equivalent to adding a setter while in the superclass there was only a getter. And this is rather important in implementing some patterns.

Secondly if you are opening a variable that means that you want to make it changeable in a subblass. Don't forget that val means **read-only** not immutable. And if you want to keep setter private you still can when you override

```
override var a = 1
    private set
```

Answer (score 0):

Because client classes will attempt to interact with Main as if it were a Test. That's the point of making Test open, so that clients will interact with its children with the expectation that those children will behave like Test and accept all of the same method calls and variable reassignments.

If Test makes a contract with all of its client users that they are allowed to change a, then Main is breaking that contract if it makes a unchangeable.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does mean `client` in your answer?

Comment: It's just fancy talk for whatever class has objects that end up using Test (or main). People often use the term "client" for a class that uses something and "service" for the class that gets used. So if a class called User uses Test at some point, then another developer at another point in time might decide to make User use Main instead because they know they can. But that developer (who isn't you and doesn't know) would find they couldn't use Main if it didn't behave like Test. That's the reason for the restriction.